# Bubble sort Arrays of User Input of Int values

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

I am trying to solve two issues I am having with this code. First I would like to set my integer input to a max of 100 and second I am trying to take the array of integers entered and sort them by absolute value. So if a user uses this program I want them to only be able to enter in 99 for the number of integers they'd like sorted. And when it is finally sorted instead of descending or ascending order I'd like it to be like this; -1,2,-6,10,-20.

```
 public static void main(String args[])
{
   int n, i, j, temp;
   int arr[] = new int[50];
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   //Input area for user data, setting the number of integers to sort
   System.out.print("Enter Total Number of Integers you would like to sort : ");
   n = scan.nextInt();

   for (n=0, n < 100, n++)

   {
   }

   //Input area for user data, asking user to input the ints into an array for sorting
   System.out.print("Enter " +n+ " Numbers : ");
   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
       arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
   }

   // Sorting Array using Bubble Sort Technique
   for(i=0; i<(n-1); i++)
   {
       for(j=0; j<(n-i-1); j++)
       {
           if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
           {
               temp = arr[j];
               arr[j] = arr[j+1];
               arr[j+1] = temp;
           }
       }
   }

   // Command line output from user, sorted by absolute value      
   System.out.print("Sorted List : \n");
   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
       System.out.print(java.lang.Math.abs(arr[i])+ "  ");
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: You didn't ask any question.

Comment: I asked how I could limit the user's ability to enter an integer of 99 or less in the initial group to enter into my array. And also how to make sure the list is sorted into a list formed by absolute value, as opposed to descending or ascending order.

Comment: as the code is, no there are no errors, but I have two issues I am asking for assistance with as I cannot figure out how to do it. I tried using java.lang.Math.abs() for my absolute value, but it did not seem to work as expected.

Comment: Well, you'll need to add code to do that: read the integer, check if it's less than 100, if not, print an error, ask it again. I'm sure you've learnt loops and if. Use them. I'm also sure you know what an absolute value is. So, instead of comparing numbers, compare their absolute value. Try something. We won't do your homework. Telling us you tried something without posting the code, and telling us that "it did not seem to work as expected" is much too vague.

Comment: I am not looking to have my homework solved, merely guidance from peers. I am sorry I thought I had uploaded code in which I had a for loop and java.lang.Math.abs() method included. Apologies.

Comment: You got some guidance. Now you need to try something based on that guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few suggestions (mostly minor) and a possible solution:

1. Code style matters! Use [appropriate indentation and spacing](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).
2. Don't declare a bunch of index variables at the top of the function. This is fine for C89 but it's not necessary in Java. Keeping variables in the narrowest scope possible can prevent bugs.
3. Use `Math.abs()` inside your sort routine rather than your print code to get your desired result.
4. Consider using an ArrayList rather than a primitive array when you're unsure of length ahead of time. Copying the array once populated to eliminate the unused tail is another reasonable approach. Otherwise, `arr.length` is inaccurate and you're stuck relying on an accompanying length variable which can cause bugs later on.
5. Consider using functions to modularize your code, especially for obviously reusable and modular components like sorting.
6. Consider using something other than a bubble sort, which is inefficient albeit appropriate for pedagogical examples such as this. Built in sort libraries like `Arrays.sort()` are the industrial strength approach.
7. `for (n=0, n < 100, n++)` is a syntax error. Use `;` to delimit the `for`. This line also overwrites the `n` value you just collected from the user with 0. Use `i` to count here or do `n--` until `n == 0` to iterate `n` times.
8. If you allow you user up to 99 integers, use an array of length 99 instead of 50 so you can hold everything.
9. `nextInt()` will crash if the user enters a non-integer. Look into [error handling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm) to deal with such cases.

Here's some code:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[] = new int[99];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        out.print("Enter total number of integers you would like to sort: ");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        while (n < 1 || n > 99) {
            out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 99: ");
            n = scan.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            out.print("Input a number less than 100: ");
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();

            if (arr[i] > 100) { 
                out.println("That number was over 100. Try again.");
                i--; 
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
                if (Math.abs(arr[j]) > Math.abs(arr[j + 1])) {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        out.println("Sorted List :");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            out.print(arr[i] + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Sample run

```
Enter total number of integers you would like to sort:  6
Input a number less than 100:  1
Input a number less than 100:  -9
Input a number less than 100:  3
Input a number less than 100:  4
Input a number less than 100:  -5
Input a number less than 100:  6
Sorted List : 
1  3  4  -5  6  -9
```